# How to replace a value with NA across an entire dataframe

Tags: r, replace, na

Is there any way to replace all the "-95" that can possibly exist in a dataframe with NA across all the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
df[df=="-95"]<-NA
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more complicated cases, where you have multiple values that shall be converted into NAs, maybe according to some specific conditions, the **naniar** package can be quite helpful. There are the following functions:

```
naniar::replace_with_na()
naniar::replace_with_na_if()
naniar::replace_with_na_at()
```

These can be quite helpful and are quite powerful. Probably the best intro is looking at the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/replace-with-na.html) of these functions.

Here a small example, if you have a dataframe with a `x` and a `z` variable and for your `x` you want to have -99 and -98 encoded to NA, while for your `z` variable you want to have -99 and -97 to be encoded to NA.

```
library(naniar)
df %>%
  replace_with_na(replace = list(x = c(-99,-98),
                             z = c(-99, -97)))
```